# Log into WSJ using Python requests

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, requests-oauthlib

I am trying to log into the Wall Street Journal's website using the Python module `requests`. I know that other people on these boards here have successfully used Selenium to accomplish the same. However, I would like to understand the workflow for this process.

Unfortunately, the OAuth 2 process is all Greek to me (and I don't speak Greek). I found the package `requests_oauthlib` that comes with a [few examples](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/examples.html), but I am having the hardest time aligning those with what happens in the Chrome console when I sign into WSJ manually. I can see some of the terms popping up in the requests (like `client_id` and `redirect_uri`) but I don't really understand what they mean so I cannot seem to connect the dots.

Is there anyone here willing and able to point me in the right direction? Just a friendly nudge towards some kind of beginner's documentation on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I ended up going the Selenium way. It turned out that logging in manually and then snatching the session cookie (using `browser-cookie3`) and adding it to Selenium was much, much simpler and acceptable within the parameters of my project.